# Initialization and changing ndb property in google-apps-engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url, google-cloud-datastore, url-parameters

I created a datastore object accoring to the guestbook tutorial:

```
class myDS(ndb.Model):
    a = ndb.StringProperty(indexed=True)
```

And I have an Handlers to access it and update is:

```
class Handler1:

    my_ds = myDS()
    my_ds.a = "abc" #Trying to update the value

class Handler2:
    my_ds = myDS()
    self.response.write(my_ds.a) #prints None although I changed the value in Handlers1

def main():
   application = webapp.WSGIApplication([
           ('/set',   Handler1),
           ('/get',   Handler2])
```

I call:

```
Myapp.com/set 
Myapp.com/get : Prints None (Didn't update to "abc")
```

Why wasn't the value of a updated?
How can I update across the handlers?

Comment: You don't do any of these things. This code makes no sense at all; you can't access `self` at class level, there wouldn't be a request even if you could, and `ds` would be a string with the value of a querystring attribute so wouldn't have an `l` attribute. Please explain exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I tried to follow the guestbook example - I want to create a data store with a list and a dictionary that will be used in the different handlers. Set Handler ('/set') to update the dict and the list, and Get Handler ('/get') to access the list

Comment: But you haven't done anything like the guestbook example. That has a class that inherits from RequestHandler, which has a `get` method, and inside that method uses the `ndb.Key` method to query the datastore. You haven't done any of those things. You need to go back and understand how GAE and webapp2 work at a basic level first, and only then worry about pickle methods.

Comment: @DanielRoseman So can you please explain how I can build a dict and a list to maintain in my engine across handlers? (i.e to use the same dict and access it in GetHandler and in other handlers as well)

Comment: No, because there are too many things you don't seem to know. First, write a handier that gets and saves a model instance with a simple string, then we can talk about more complex types.

Comment: @DanielRoseman That the problem - I can't understand from many tutorial how I get it done for a simple string. Once I get this, extrapolate to dict won't be a problem :) How I do it for a simple string/int?

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/

Comment: @DanielRoseman Please see my edit with my new code - I can init but can't update between the handlers.

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [this documentation](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/tools/using-local-server#using_the_local_datastore) to help you understand how the Google Cloud DataStore works and also [how to use the Webapp2 framework for developing your code](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/gettingstarted/introduction.html).

Answer (score 1):

Cloud Datastore (GCD) [stores data objects as entities](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/creating-entities), which may have one or more properties. In your case the property value type is a string 'abc'. However each entity is identified by a key which is a unique identifier within your app's datastore.

So in your case you would need to create a key for object my_ds and also define a model class. That could be Handler1 (e.g. `class Handler1(ndb.Model): #your code`) which defines the property you are trying to call.

Additionally, you cannot expect the value to be updated without using the put() function (e.g. `my_ds.put()` ). In order to use the second handler (Handler2) to create a new object and set the values of the properties you need to learn a bit more about using [Webapp2 request handler](http://webapp2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorials/gettingstarted/introduction.html).

I also suggest you follow this [tutorial to get started](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/getting-started/storing-data-datastore).